# How to customize Verify your identity (entering verification code) screen in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have created Connected App in Salesfoce and have customized the login screen (changing logo, button css etc., using Visualforce). When user logs in for the first time or logs in from different browser or device, it prompts for 'Verify your identity' (to enter verification code).

I know we can customize the option of sending the verification code to mobile or email. But, I would like to customize the 'Verify your Identity' screen like changing the logo, button css etc. I didn't find it under Visualforce Pages.

Where is this located and how can the styles be customized?

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible in Winter '20. From [Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_identity_user_verify_phone_or_email.htm):

> When external users register a verification method, either a phone
>   number or email address, Salesforce displays a Verify page for users
>   to enter their verification code. You can replace the default Verify
>   page with your own, for example, to reflect your brand or meet your
>   corporate guidelines